# generate array of unique uuid in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I would like to insert array of unique uuid values in table with uuid column as primary key. Table structure is

```
CREATE TABLE Organisation (uuid id PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4());
```

e.g. I have 2 organisations, so I am trying to implement it with query looks like

```
INSERT INTO Organisation (uuid) VALUES (unnest(array_fill(uuid_generate_v4()::uuid, ARRAY[2]))) RETURNING uuid as uuid_org;
```

It fails with

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "organisation_pkey"
```

because query fairly tries to insert two duplicated not-unique values, e.g.

```
{711ec909-fc2c-45aa-8912-39207788768e,711ec909-fc2c-45aa-8912-39207788768e}
```

My trick works when **RETURNING** ids or uuids while inserting in tables with not the only column - I pass the uuid column and query automatically generate unique uuids that I can aggregate (see below for table TimeSlice).

Generally, my idea is to insert simultaneously in several tables using **WITH**:

```
WITH ins_ts as (INSERT INTO TimeSlice (validTimeBegin) VALUES 
             (unnest(array_fill('2020-01-02'::datetype, ARRAY[2])))
             RETURNING id as id_ts),
     ins_org AS (INSERT INTO Organisation (uuid) ... ---my fail query ),
INSERT INTO OrganisationTimeSlice (idTimeSlice, uuid, name) 
            VALUES (unnest(array(select array_agg(id_ts) from ins_ts)), 
    (unnest(array(select array_agg(uuid_org) from ins_org))),
                     unnest(array['name1', 'name2']));
```

Where am I wrong?

To clarify why this needs to be an array instead of e.g. explicitly providing two rows like this:

```
INSERT INTO Organisation (uuid) VALUES (uuid_generate_v4()), (uuid_generate_v4())
```

This is because I have a variable number of organisations, that I set in `ARRAY[number_of_organisations]`.  Therefore I need to generate a variable number of uuids.

Answer (score 2):

*N.B.: This was originally suggested by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1822/a-horse-with-no-name) in a comment.*

The [solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/258432) by [fds](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/198769/fds) can be simplified to

```
select uuid_generate_v4() from generate_series(1,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't actually want them in an array, since you are unnesting it right away, here's how to generate a table of any amount of UUIDs:

```
WITH RECURSIVE genx(n, uu) AS (
  VALUES (1, uuid_generate_v4())
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1, uuid_generate_v4()
  FROM genx WHERE n < 30
) SELECT uu FROM genx;
```

Change the 30 to as many as you want!